# Is it possible to keep aws codedeploy test listener for some minutes to manually tests before traffic is routed to prod?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ecs, aws-code-deploy, aws-code-deploy-appspec

I made a aws ecs fargate blue/green continuos deployment using aws codepipeline. It is working properly, but I need to have a test URL before new code version turn to prod. I enabled `Test listener` option in `codedeploy deployment group` then tried to run pipeline, but the test stage didn't wait nothing ... then I changed `Deployment settings -> Traffic rerouting to Specify when to reroute traffic (5 minutes)`. Then tried to run pipeline again, then the test stage waited 5 minutes, then we could do the manual tests but then a new issue came after 5 minutes:

> The deployment timed out while waiting for a notification to continue. This time out period is 5 minutes.

I found a possible solution using `appspec.yml hooks` to tell the deployment to continue, then I created a lambda function with properly permissions and changed my `appspec.yml` to:

```yaml
version: 0.0
Resources:
  - TargetService:
      Type: AWS::ECS::Service
      Properties:
        TaskDefinition: "<TASK_DEFINITION>"
        LoadBalancerInfo:
          ContainerName: "****"
          ContainerPort: 5231
Hooks:
    - AfterAllowTestTraffic: "ARN_LAMBDA_FUNCTION"
```

**Lambda function:**

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const codedeploy = new aws.CodeDeploy({apiVersion: '2014-10-06'});

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    //Read the DeploymentId from the event payload.
    var deploymentId = event.DeploymentId;

    //Read the LifecycleEventHookExecutionId from the event payload
    var lifecycleEventHookExecutionId = event.LifecycleEventHookExecutionId;

    /*
     Enter validation tests here.
    */

    // Prepare the validation test results with the deploymentId and
    // the lifecycleEventHookExecutionId for CodeDeploy.
    var params = {
        deploymentId: deploymentId,
        lifecycleEventHookExecutionId: lifecycleEventHookExecutionId,
        status: 'Succeeded' // status can be 'Succeeded' or 'Failed'
    };
    
    // Pass CodeDeploy the prepared validation test results.
    codedeploy.putLifecycleEventHookExecutionStatus(params, function(err, data) {
        
        console.log("Err => ", err);
        console.log("Data => ",data);
        
        if (err) {
            // Validation failed.
            callback('Validation test failed');
        } else {
            console.log("success!");
            // Validation succeeded.
            callback(null, 'Validation test succeeded');
        }
    });
};
```

Then tried to run pipeline again ... lambda function was executed and `putLifecycleEventHookExecutionStatus` returned `lifecycleEventHookExecutionId`, but the deployment returned the same error as above.

What am I doing wrong?